# Is it allowed/desirable to post code snippets?

Tags: discussion, code, source-code

Instead of asking a question I would love to share the one or other code snippet I have created that is too small to make a full article on e.g. CodeProject.com or CodePlex.com.

**Question:** Would it be a good idea to post it as a Stack Overflow question? Or are there any other suggestions how to share it?

*(Of course I could post it on my own weblog and then twitter about it, but I would love to put it in more of a programming context)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Posting a question, to which you already have a solution, is perfectly acceptable in my opinion.  You would then post your solution as one possible one.  A link to a fuller explanation may or may not be appropriate depending on the answer.  I would be very careful to avoid the appearance of trying to *market* your solution, though.  I think you'll find that people are very sensitive to spam and if your posts looks like spam, it will probably be unmercifully voted down.  Even it it doesn't you may still get some downvotes from people who don't understand that it's ok to post answers to your own questions.

One thing that I would also suggest is that you be explicitly open to alternative solutions.  Be genuinely interested in other answers to your question -- and write your question from that perspective.  "I ran into this problem doing foo the other day and was able to solve it (solution posted as an answer), but I'd be interested in other, perhaps better solutions?" would be the tack I would take.  In my mind, if you are still looking for solutions, then the question is not in doubt as to its legitimacy.  And, please do vote up other answers that are useful.

Lastly, I would only do this rarely -- it might be that many of your questions take this route, but then I would expect that your questions are asked more rarely.  A pattern of posting questions that are really links to your blog or some code you are marketing will be detected and will not be appreciated by many.

Answer (score 2):

You could pose a question with the problem you were trying to solve and then post your answer a few days later.

Or, you could post the problem as a Code Golf type question and either include your solution in the question or as the first answer.